# Not able to figure out from where I can get, redirect URI

Tags: azure-active-directory, zoho

I am trying to setup, zoho federated signin with Azure AD, I am following below documentation
https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/kb/desk/for-administrators/user-access-and-security/articles/enabling-federated-login-for-help-center

this documentation says I will get Redirect URI value from the Meta Data section of Microsoft's page in Zoho Desk.

But I am not able to find it, or way to navigate

Comment: check if this helps: https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/kb/accounts/manage-your-organization/saml/articles/access-zoho-via-azure

Comment: Thanks for documentation reference  !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup federated login with Azure, you can use SAML for sign-in

Create your own application in Enterprise Applications in Azure AD with Integrate any other application you don't find in the gallery option for what are you looking to do with your application?

Sign in to your Zoho Account. Under SAML Authentication, click on Download Metadata

Copy the Entity ID and ACS URL from the Metadata Document

Go to your application in Azure AD and paste the entity ID and Reply URL as ACS URL. Also add the Sign On URL

Finally, configure the Azure Details in Zoho

For detailed information, you can refer this document: [Accessing Zoho via Azure using SAML](https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/kb/accounts/manage-your-organization/saml/articles/access-zoho-via-azure#Required_items_from_Azure)